# Developing a bin file from firmware

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, bin, firmware, hardware

I have a firmware file with a **.bin** extension and I am looking to modify it. I have successfully extracted the code out of it, I just want to rebuild it as **bin** file. Is there any tool to make a .bin file just like we do the rar or zip?

I don't want to compile the file or make it actually run, just want the bin file out of it.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the firmware file format. It's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @MargaretBloom well I just thought there must be some way to "bin" a file just like we do the compression.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not. `bin` is a generic extension (even `zip` means slightly different formats). It's akin to asking how to "txt" something. You need to find the file format, not the extension. As you already extracted the code, you surely know the format of the binary file. Once you have the format you can look for a tool.

Answer (score 0):

All file types are valid `.bin` files without modifying the data. Just change the file extension to `.bin` and open it in the hex editor of your choice.